# Is there a word for this opposite reaction you can have when you meet someone after a long time?

Tags: neologisms

These are the feelings/emotion I would like to describe with a word:

You have been really a close friend of another person for many many years, and then you stopped hanging out together and even calling at telephone. Then you suddenly met at a party. You manage do to only small talk and nobody knows really what to say. There's a general embarrassment and you end up without speaking too much.

The opposite situation is when you meet at a party somebody who you weren't in touch with for so long, and both are more than happy to met, and it is as only a few days have passed since the last time.

How would you name these stuff?

Comment: *We drifted apart* and *We were long-lost friends*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first situation:

*"We no longer had anything in common."*

*"We had become strangers."*

For the second: *"We just picked up where we left off."*

The first is an *"awkward **interaction**."*

The other is a *"happy **reunion**."*

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure someone will eventually have one but I don't have one word for it. Until then, please consider what I use and think I made up. It is self-explanatory.

A tributary or affluent is

> a stream or river that flows into a larger stream or main stem (or parent) river or a lake. For this to happen, the break apart or part ways at some point.

A confluence is

> the flowing together of two or more streams
>
> the place of meeting of two streams
>
> the combined stream formed by conjunction.

One could say, **"the confluence of two affluents/tributaries, " "they are affluents/tributaries at a confluence" or "affluents/tributaries in a confluence."**

It would try to delineate that two friends(two streams) parted ways long ago but are now reunited (a confluence) in a way that is remarkable because after the confluence you can't tell the two streams apart. It's as if they never steered away